# Como obtener lista de archivos con ssh2 sftp usando php?

Tags: php, sftp

Estoy probando hacer un par de cosas con sftp, ya instale la dll y me funciona correctamente.
*Por ahora logre traer un archivo de mi ftp al escritorio y mandar archivos al ftp* ando buscando info pero es casi nula y los ejemplos que encontré no me funcionaron... me gustaría imprimir la lista de archivos que tengo en el servidor... como seria posible?, algún manual?, me fije en php.net pero nada...

Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Lo pude solucionar, por si a alguno le interesa le dejo el siguiente script

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
$sftp_fd = intval($sftp);

$handle = opendir("ssh2.sftp://$sftp_fd/path/to/directory");
echo "Directory handle: $handle\n";
echo "Entries:\n";
while (false != ($entry = readdir($handle))){
    echo "$entry\n";
}
```